# floating list with 100% width and margins

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm working on an element on my website, but it gives me some headaches.

Here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

I would like to use `<li>`-items for each 33% "column" and it is important that there are no margins on the left or right of the list. The first list-element should start where the container starts and the last element should end where the container ends but at the same time, the list elements need to be same width.

Because of the margin, the width is more than 100% and the last `<li>`-element goes into a new line. Everything else I tried produced different widths for at least one of the `<li>`-elements.

I thought about percentage-margins, but I really want to have 30px if possible.

The huge problem is that everything needs to be responsive, the `<li>`-width cannot be a fixed value.

Check out the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paelzersebbi/FAtVB/

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <ul>
      <li>Content 1</li>
      <li>Content 2</li>
      <li>Content 3</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#wrapper {width: 80%; height: 300px; background: #F30;}
ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
li {width: 33.3%; height: 150px; float: left; background-color: #FFF; margin-right:10px;}
li:last-child {margin-right: 0;}
.clear {clear: both;}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to have 30px, and not a percentage, as web-tiki said before, you could always use [`calc`](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) from CSS3. Browser support is fairly good (IE9+)

```
li {
  width:calc( 33.33% - 30px );
  margin-left:30px
}
```

Pay attention to spacing! `calc(33.33%-30px)` won't work; you actually must have spaces around hypen: `calc(33.33% - 30px)`

Comment: The way it is used here won't give the desired magins. But it a way to go

Comment: It's good, but browser-support might be an issue, I don't know. Maybe I'll use your idea if nothing else comes around ;) It is at least elegant.

Comment: Desired margins can be achieved by changing the math: total margin is 60px between the three `<li>`. Therefore it is `33.33% - 20px` (60px / 3 elements).

Comment: @web-tiki: i updated the example to include the margin as well.

Comment: @paelzer: browser support is ie9+, see the updated link. Depending on current site stats, you can either use my example or search further for some weird hacks.

Please consider YOUR site stats, not statcounter or anything else (statcounter shows ~15% IE8 marketshare, but on my sites i have less than 1%; on most client sites i have less than 5%; on one client site it's around 85% IE8).

Comment: @IonutStaicu to use the calc technique you must do this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/FAtVB/3/ please update your calculation to make it reflect the OP's desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use percent margins, you just need to make sure :

```
width of all <li> + all left/right margins = 100%
```

### Example :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/FAtVB/1/)**

CSS :

```
li {
    width: 32.3%;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-right:1.5%;
}
li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

**EDIT: if your gaps have a solid colour**

You can use borders and the `box-sizing` property to include the border size in the width value.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/FAtVB/2/)**

```
li {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

li:nth-child(1){
    border-right:20px solid #F30;
}
li:nth-child(2){
    border-left:10px solid #F30;
    border-right:10px solid #F30;
}
li:last-child {
    border-left:20px solid #F30;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I already thought about that. However, I really wanted to stick with the 30px margin. But I have the feeling that I need to go with percentages...

Answer (score 1):

Try using display: table, and display: table-cell.

http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/rpEqv

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      <ul>
      <li>Content 1</li>
      <li>Content 2</li>
      <li>Content 3</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   *, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
li { height: 150px; display: table-cell; padding-right:30px; background: silver; list-style-type: none; position: relative; }

li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;

}
li:last-child:after {width: 0}
#wrapper {width: 100%; display: table}
ul {
  display: table; width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Also very nice. Now I can't decide what I like more ;)

Comment: @paelzer this is what happens when you ask good questions with all the necessary elements for answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `display: table`. Note: This is not a "table layout", because it doesn't abuse `<table>` semantics in HTML.

You can omit your wrapping container:

```
<ul>
    <li>Content 1</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
    <li>Content 3</li>
</ul>
```

Your CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    /* otherwise border-spacing would be collapsed */
    border-collapse: separate;
    /* I don't know, why it's x y here instead of y x (like for padding etc.) */
    border-spacing: 30px 0;
    /* your width + 2*30px because of negative margin */
    width: calc(80% + 60px);
    /* otherwise, left and right elements would have border-spacing */
    margin: 0 -30px; 
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.33333%;
    background-color: #fff;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/FAtVB/4/

However, if you want another color as your background of the `<ul>`, you'll need the wrapping container.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Do you maybe know if I can use the `table`-properties to somehow make each `<li>`-element the same height depending on the content of the highest `<li>`?

Comment: Sorry, I looked at the fiddle after I commented. It already solves my problem as it is. thanks.

Comment: @paelzer It's the nature of a table that all cells in a row have the same height. ;-)

Comment: There is just one problem left: I have links inside each `<li>`. They are supposed to cover all of the `<li>`-element but they won't. Any ideas?

Comment: @paelzer One possible solution is to use absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/FAtVB/5/ – don't forget to upvote my answer if it helps. ;-)

Comment: @paelzer did you notice the `position: relative` for `<li>`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I need to get a couple of `<div>`-containers into the `<a>`-tag but that keeps screwing things up.

Comment: @paelzer A couple of `<div>`s in a `<a>`, what do you plan?

Answer (score 1):

you can use css align-content :space-between;
more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_align-content&preval=stretch)